# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found -- IIS- Windows 7

Tags: php, iis, mysqli

I got this error whenever I open my project. This project can run on my other laptop which is using XAMPP. 
I want to use IIS 6.0 on my Windows 7 Pro.
I already installed IIS, Setting environment variable, remove semicolon on my php.ini-development, add handler. So confusing and still not get the right answer.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SIA-2\general\function.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SIA-2\general\initial.php(10): open_connection() #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SIA-2\index.php(41): include_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SIA-2\general\function.php on line 8

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B66OIQlx1mwzc0JVbVhjX0U0aDQ&usp=sharing

please do not give me any documentation. i'm sick of it. thank you.